# How to subset pandas DataFrame whose column values are lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` that looks like this:

```
A      B
0  ['a','b']
1  ['c','d']
2  ['a','c']
3  ['b','d']
4  ['a','d']
```

Now, I wish to subset `df` by only selecting those rows in which `'a'` belongs to the list in `B`, the desired output being:

```
A      B
0  ['a','b']
2  ['a','c'] 
4  ['a','d']
```

Naively, I tried `df['a' in df['B']]`, but this doesn't seem to work. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `apply` is one way to filter.

```
In [39]: df[df['B'].apply(lambda x: 'a' in x)]
Out[39]:
   A       B
0  0  [a, b]
2  2  [a, c]
4  4  [a, d]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the length of the lists are the same across all rows, here's a vectorized approach -

```
df[(df.B.values=='a').any(1)]
```

If `df.B.values` creates an array of Object dtype, we might need to use a flattening operation there with `np.concatenate`, like so -

```
df[(np.concatenate(df.B)=='a').reshape(len(df),-1).any(1)]
```